# Identify columns containing dictionaries in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataset which is similar to:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'col2': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
'col3': [{'lol':1,'lol2':'a'},{'lol':2,'lol2':'b'},{'lol':4,'lol2':'n'}, 
{'lol':1,'lol2':'a'},{'lol':1,'lol2':'a'},{'lol':1,'lol2':'a'}, 
{'lol':1,'lol2':'a'}]})
```

I am trying to find a way to identify the column(s) that contain dictionaries.
In this example it would be 'col3'

The ideal output would be a list of the column names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to loop through the columns and check whether the first element in each is a dict. Note, this works for the case given and assumes that any column that contains dicts contains *only* dicts

```
[i for i in df.columns if isinstance(df[i][0],dict)]

['col3']
```

Comment: works exactly how i need it to for my case where every value is a dict