# How to check if a pandas DF column has dictionary in it?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

Referring to this Thread: [Identify columns containing dictionaries in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229483/identify-columns-containing-dictionaries-in-pandas)

The above one will find the columns if it has a list of dictionaries. I want to find if the column values are 'a' dictionary. If yes, how to convert them to columns of its own.

Tried everything mentioned here: [Identify columns containing dictionaries in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229483/identify-columns-containing-dictionaries-in-pandas)

Comment: What did you try? What error did you get?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your post to include a sample of your data as a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example, the code you've tried, your current result and your expected result.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to know how to convert a DataFrame column, made up entirely of `dict` values with a fixed key set, into a range of new columns represented by the dictionary keys.

---

### 1) Example DataFrame

Consider the DataFrame from the [question you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229483/identify-columns-containing-dictionaries-in-pandas) (with an extra column added to better demonstrate this solution):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Construct a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],

    'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],

    'col3': [{'lol':1, 'lol2':'a'},{'lol':2, 'lol2':'b'},{'lol':4, 'lol2':'n'}, 
             {'lol':1, 'lol2':'a'},{'lol':1, 'lol2':'a'},{'lol':1, 'lol2':'a'}, 
             {'lol':1, 'lol2':'a'}],

    'col4': ['b', {'x':0}, 'a', {'x':2}, {'x': 4}, {'x':1}, 'c']
})

print(df)
```

```
   col1 col2                     col3      col4
0     1    a  {'lol': 1, 'lol2': 'a'}         b
1     2    b  {'lol': 2, 'lol2': 'b'}  {'x': 0}
2     3    c  {'lol': 4, 'lol2': 'n'}         a
3     4    d  {'lol': 1, 'lol2': 'a'}  {'x': 2}
4     5    e  {'lol': 1, 'lol2': 'a'}  {'x': 4}
5     6    f  {'lol': 1, 'lol2': 'a'}  {'x': 1}
6     7    g  {'lol': 1, 'lol2': 'a'}         c
```

Output of `df.info()`:

```
RangeIndex: 7 entries, 0 to 6
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   col1    7 non-null      int64 
 1   col2    7 non-null      object
 2   col3    7 non-null      object
 3   col4    7 non-null      object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 352.0+ bytes
```

---

### 2) Determining which columns are made up of `dict` values.

The following code can be used to test each column to check whether all its values are of type `dict`:

```py
# Get a Series of booleans which represent whether each column of the DataFrame is made entirely of dicts.
is_dict = df.transform(lambda x: x.apply(type).eq(dict)).all()
```

Details:

- [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html): applies a function to each column.
- [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html): used by the mapping function to get the data type of each value in the column.
- [`.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html): chained onto `apply()` to test whether each type is a `dict`, outputting results as `bool` values.
- [`.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html): applied to the resulting DataFrame of `bool` values, to test for each column whether ALL its value are `True` (i.e. it is made up entirely of dictionaries).

As a general function:

```py
def column_is_type(df, t):
    return df.transform(lambda x: x.apply(type).eq(t)).all()

# Usage 
column_is_type(df, dict)
```

Output:

```
col1    False
col2    False
col3     True
col4    False
dtype: bool
```

---

### 3) Converting  a column of `dict` values to a DataFrame

For `col3`, we can extract it from the DataFrame, converting it to a list of `dict` values. It can then be converted to a DataFrame and be added onto the original.

**Warning**: It is assumed that each dictionary stored is of the same structure (i.e. the key set is fixed). Otherwise a column will be created for every single key found an any of the dictionaries, with `NaN` values being produced out of the dictionaries that do not use them all.

```py
# First extract col3, converting to a list
col3_dicts = list(df['col3'])

# Get the numeric index of column 3
col_index = df.columns.get_loc('col3')

# Convert it into a DataFrame
dict_df = pd.DataFrame(col3_dicts)

# Concatenate these columns, sandwiched between the columns on the left and right of col3 (which will be excluded).
new_df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :col_index], dict_df, df.iloc[:,col_index+1:]], axis=1)
```

As a general function:

```py
def dict_to_cols(df, col):

    col3_dicts = list(df[col])
    
    col_index = df.columns.get_loc(col)
    
    dict_df = pd.DataFrame(col3_dicts)

    new_df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :col_index], dict_df, df.iloc[:,col_index+1:] ], axis=1)

    new_df[dict_df.columns] = dict_df
    
    return new_df

# Usage:
dict_to_cols(df, 'col3')
```

---

### 4) Putting it altogether:

```py
# --- The main function ---

# Takes a DataFrame and converts every column of dictionaries into sub-DatFrames in their own right.
def convert_dicts(df):
    # Check whether each column is a dictionary.
    dict_checks = column_is_type(df, dict)
    # Get the column names of the DataFrame (save it as a copy since df.columns is dynamic)
    col_names = list(df.columns)
    
    # Iterate over the index of each of these columns.
    for i in range(0, len(col_names)):
        
        # If the column is filled with dictionaries, "stretch it out".
        if dict_checks[i]:
            df = dict_to_cols(df, col_names[i])
            
    return df
```

```py
# --- Sub functions ---

# Tests each column of the given DataFrame of whether it is made entirely of the given type t.
def column_is_type(df, t):
    return df.transform(lambda x: x.apply(type).eq(t)).all()


# Converts a column of dictionaries to a DataFrame and adds it onto the one given.
def dict_to_cols(df, col):

    col3_dicts = list(df[col])
    
    col_index = df.columns.get_loc(col)
    
    dict_df = pd.DataFrame(col3_dicts)

    new_df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :col_index], dict_df, df.iloc[:,col_index+1:]], axis=1)

    new_df[dict_df.columns] = dict_df
    
    return new_df
```

Running `convert_dicts(df)` will produce:

```
   col1 col2  lol lol2      col4
0     1    a    1    a         b
1     2    b    2    b  {'x': 0}
2     3    c    4    n         a
3     4    d    1    a  {'x': 2}
4     5    e    1    a  {'x': 4}
5     6    f    1    a  {'x': 1}
6     7    g    1    a         c
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!

Option 2 worked perfectly!!! Thank you.